# how to find the location of a character located right-most among all such characters in python?

Tags: python, string, find

Consider the  following sentence, I'd like to locate the right-most `"`(double quote) before `#`, where in this example the answer should be the double quote after `?`.  How to solve it in Python? Do you have any good idea ?

```
print("Hello, world!", "Can you tell me the answer?") # this is a "comment"
```

Comment: `findRightMost = lambda myStr,target,delim : max(i for i,char in enumerate(itertools.takewhile(lambda c: c!=delim, myStr)) if char==target)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string by `#` and then use `rfind("\"")` on the first item in the list.

```
string.split("#")[0].rfind("\"")
```

Comment: Great! str.split() is the key!

Comment: Besides, we can also locate '#' first and then attack '"', i.e. nsharp = string.find('#'); nquote = string[:nsharp].rfind('\"')